# Could not start ADB in mac OS

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

My android studio is showing the error like `~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb start-server' failed -- run manually if necessary`. I saw there are a lot of solutions but none of them working for me.

I have ensured the following things

1. No other adb is running in the background
2. No process hold 5037 port
3. No java process running in the background
4. Restarted the android studio - still, the issue is there
5. Restarted the Laptop - Still the issue is there
6. Shutdown the laptop and then start again - **This is working only once in around 5 trials**
7. upgraded the adb

When I enabled the log by setting `ADB_TRACE=all` in terminal, the adb is hanging after the following logs

```
$ platform-tools$ adb start-server
adb D 07-19 10:36:41 91712 171954 adb_trace.cpp:187] Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
adb D 07-19 10:36:41 91712 171954 adb_trace.cpp:187] Version 31.0.2-7242960
adb D 07-19 10:36:41 91712 171954 adb_trace.cpp:187] Installed as /usr/local/bin/adb
adb D 07-19 10:36:41 91712 171954 adb_trace.cpp:187]
adb D 07-19 10:36:41 91712 171954 adb_client.cpp:346] adb_connect: service: host:start-server
adb D 07-19 10:36:41 91712 171954 adb_client.cpp:155] _adb_connect: host:version
```

Can anyone help me to sort out this issue?

Comment: Which version of MacOS/Apple device are you using?

Comment: MacOS High Sierra, Version 10.13.6

Comment: I am also running the same version of MacOS, same adb version. One different thing is that my copy prints `Installed as /Users/XXXX/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb` I am using Android Studio 4.2.2 and I didn't move any of the SDK files from the library directory while you seem to have moved the `adb` file to `/usr/local/bin/adb`

Comment: This log is taken from the terminal only. I am getting the same log even if I execute it from the Android studio. In that case the adb is taking from platform-tools directory itself

Comment: My android studio version is 4.2.1, let me check in latest version